# Creating and using an android library project

Tags: android

My goal is to have a library project that contains a common set of code, layouts, assets, and other external libraries (for advertising, etc) and then create two separate android apps that use that code, but just swap out some of the constants and layout graphics.

I started with what is described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

The library project is essentially a completely working app on its own, save for the "Is Library" checkbox.

But when I build the app's project, I get an error saying its looking for the library's APK on the device.

I then changed the "activity" nodes in the app's manifest to , but then I get "INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY" from the device.

Comment: Did you reference the library project in the application you're building?

Answer (score 1):

You may get this by defining the project as a "required project" in the "Java Build Path" rather than a "reference" in the "Android" section of project/properties.  In that case the project will compile, but fail at runtime as you describe.